# How to see if a string is in a text file (kinda) ? python

Tags: python, discord

I'm writing a discord bot that is looking for a few things:

1) It checks if the user who sent the command's name is already in the file, the user who sent the message is "member" variable.

2) If the user is not in the file it should add their name to the file.

3) If the user is in the file, it sends them a message saying they cant add their name twice.

The code below I've tried different variations of and still cant quite get it. Print (current_name) is there so I can see if the code is looping through all lines of the text file, and only when I try to read the lines of the file and see if member is not in them, it doesn't print all the names to console. If you need more code please lmk.

```
            source_file_name = 'tracker.txt'
            temporary_file_name = 'tracker_temp.txt'
            with open(source_file_name, mode='r') as source_file:
                with open(temporary_file_name, mode='w') as temporary_file:
                    for current_line in source_file:
                        line_splitted = current_line.split()
                        current_name = line_splitted[0]
                        print(current_name)

                        if str(member) not in source_file.readlines():
                            output_line = str(member) + "\n"
                            temporary_file.write(output_line)

                        elif current_name == str(member):
                            output_line = str(member) + "\n"
                            mporary_file.write(output_line)
                            await client.send_message(message.channel, "You cannot redeem another role while your other role is still active!")

                        else:
                            output_line = current_name + "\n"
                            temporary_file.write(output_line)

            os.replace(temporary_file_name, source_file_name)
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: A suggestion rather than a solution : use a dictionnary a list or some other object of your liking to store the information about users and only periodically dump the data to a file. Having your program constantly parsing through a file doesnt sound optimal.

Comment: Would it be accurate to break down the workflow as:
1) Get the names in the file

2) Determine if the 'member' is one of the names from step 1

3) Add the member to the file if step 2 is false

4) Respond to the user if step 2 is true?

Comment: And can you provide a sample input file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to understand you question in the last paragraph.
What you need to change is this:

```
with open(source_file_name, mode='r') as source_file:
    with open(temporary_file_name, mode='w') as temporary_file:
        content = source_file.readlines() # gives you a list of all the lines
        for line in content:
            current_name = line.split(' ')[0]
            print current_name
```

This will result in:

```
# result of source_file.readlines():
# content = ['Name1 asd fgh', 'Name2 qwe rty']
# Console: 
# "Name1"
# "Name2"
```

Please provide more info, so I can help with it.

Comment: Why are you trying to read in the output file? Unless I am missing something there is no way you could have come to the result you have, given the information in the question.

Comment: The code is not iterating through all the lines and so the console doesn't print all the names. Read the last paragraph in his question.

Comment: I see. I missed that content was something you defined as a sample input. Either way, the first part of my comment stands, why are you trying to read in the output file?